# Handle a multiple csvs in Dask

Tags: python, dask

I have 24 separate csv files corresponding to some monthly data. Each of them takes approximately 2 GB on disk, but the exact number of rows varies.
I want to preprocess every csv while preserving their ordering time. From what I read in Dask docs, if I set number of partiions with `.repartition()`, it would just divide all data in 24 equal chunks, which will result in mixing samples from two months in one file. Is there any way to process each file separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the dask.dataframe.read_csv function with a string that points to all of your files

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv("/path/to/*.csv")
```

Dask will likely order things correctly.  It will order the files lexicographically, and then will maintain order within each file.  It may choose to break up each file into many smaller partitions, but still it will retain order.  Additionally, the partitioning created from the `read_csv` call won't needlessly mix different files.

So, maybe just use the default partitioning from `read_csv`, and don't try to change the partitioning yourself.

Comment: Well I did it in a first place, but got a few hundred partitions. Docs say that one partition should be roughly 100 mb, which Dask, I guess, tries to maintain.

Comment: You can control block size with the `blocksize=` parameter